# AJAX form not working, still reloads on submit

Tags: ajax, javascript, nonce

I've built a like and unlike system for users, and it works amazingly. The only problem is the page reloads, therefore, I've tried to set up AJAX to submit the form without a page refresh. However, it's still not working and the submit button still refreshes the page.

Maybe I am doing something wrong here?

**functions.php**

```
function op_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'op-ajax', admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) );wp_enqueue_script( 'op-post-like-ajax', get_template_directory_uri() . '/ext/js/post_like_ajax.js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'op_scripts' );
```

Here I'm calling the admin AJAX, which is what I was told to do by a fellow developer friend - maybe this is where I am going wrong?

**post_like_ajax.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

    $('#like-post').submit(function(e)){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({ 
             data: {action: 'like_post', name: 'like_post'},
             type: 'post',
             url: ajaxurl,      
             success: function(data) {
                  alert(data); 
            }
        });
    };

    $('#unlike-post').submit(function(e)){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({ 
             data: {action: 'unlike_post', name: 'unlike_post'},
             type: 'post',
             url: ajaxurl,      
             success: function(data) {
                  alert(data); 
            }
        });
    };

});
```

**post_like.php**

```
function post_likes() {
    if( is_user_logged_in() ){
        global $post;
        $post_id = $post->ID;
        global $current_user; 
        $user_id = $current_user->ID; 
        $liked_user_id = get_post_meta($post_id, '_post_likes', true); ?>
        <div id="post-options">
            <div id="post-likes">
                <?php if( $user_id == $liked_user_id ){ ?>
                    <form name="like_post" id="like_post" method="POST" action="like_post">
                        <button type="submit" name="unlike_post_<?php echo $post_id ?>"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>
                    </form>
                    <?php if(isset($_POST['unlike_post_' . $post_id])){
                        delete_post_meta($post_id, '_post_likes', $user_id);
                    } 
                } elseif( $user_id != $liked_user_id ) { ?>
                    <form name="unlike_post" id="unlike_post" method="POST" action="unlike_post">
                        <button type="submit" name="like_post_<?php echo $post_id ?>"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></button>
                    </form>
                    <?php if(isset($_POST['like_post_' . $post_id])){
                        add_post_meta($post_id, '_post_likes', $user_id);
                    } 
                } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php }

}
add_action('wp_ajax_post_likes', 'post_likes');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_post_likes', 'post_likes');
```

It's a pretty clean system besides the AJAX not working, but I just need it to not refresh the page upon liking and unliking the post otherwise the user will lose where they are down the page.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Add `e.preventDefault()` before the `$.ajax()` call in the `submit()` callback function. You're also missing a `)`, which should close the `submit()`.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I have added and updated my code.

Comment: I've got the AJAX to work, I have updated. The only problem I am having now is the state of the button changing. So maybe I need a refresh on success?

Comment: Hi Jake. Apologize for not being to reply back at that time. Hopefully you already found a solution or a workaround.